# Armazenar conteúdo de arquivo em vetor em C

Tags: c, arquivo, array

Preciso ler um arquivo texto e armazenar cada palavra do arquivo em uma posição do vetor.
A leitura foi feita normalmente e o arquivo foi passado por parâmetro tal como a quantidade de palavras.

O código realiza o armazenamento de forma estranha. Quando tento imprimir, aparece uma chuva de caracteres aleatórios.

Código:

```
void armazena_vetor(FILE* dicionario, int numero_palavras) //armazena o dicionario em um vetor
{

    char vetor_palavras[numero_palavras][15];
    int posicao;
    int i;

    posicao = 0;
    printf("%d", numero_palavras);

    while(((fscanf(dicionario, "%s", vetor_palavras[posicao])) != EOF) && (posicao < numero_palavras)) //Escreve uma palavra em cada posicao do vetor
    {
        posicao++; //Incremento de posicao
    }

    for (i=0;i<numero_palavras;i++) //teste imprime
    {
        printf("%s \n", vetor_palavras[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Como esta a estrutura do arquivo seu que contem as palavras?

Comment: É um dicionário.txt:
Abacaxi
Abacate....
.
.
.
Onde as palavras são separadas por "\n"

Comment: Sim, como esta o organizado as palavras no arquivo, em lista?

Comment: Poste seu codigo que chama a sua funçao `armazena_palavra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como é que sabes quantas palavras o ficheiro tem?

A minha intuição diz-me que já fizeste a leitura do ficheiro uma vez, antes de chamares esta função, e que portanto o apontador interno do ficheiro se encontra no fim.

Precisas de fazer o apontador interno do ficheiro voltar ao principio! Usa [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html)

```
fseek(dicionario, 0, SEEK_SET); // apontar para o principio
```

Sem voltares ao principio, o teu `while` não faz nada deixando o array `vetor_palavras` não incializado, com lixo.

<sup>Outra coisa: O uso de "`while(!feof())`" ou parecido está errado!</sup>

Comment: O erro estava ocorrendo quando eu pedia para o fscanf escrever no vetor(char**).
Corrigi o erro usando a função fseek(), como proposto pelo colega e pedindo para que o fscanf escrevesse em uma string (char*) e depois utilizando a função strcpy() da biblioteca string.h para copiar o conteúdo da string para o vetor na posição desejada.
Problema resolvido.